# What is the need to define a function to return a class's attribute?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

I came across some code like this

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age
```

Could you please explain the purpose of the function `get_age()`? If we want to know a student's age, can't we simply do this:

```
student = Student(20)
student_age = student.age
```

Comment: It allows changes like retrieving the attribute from a different place or by calculation without changing the code that calls the function. By the way: The usual Python approach is a property (looks like an attribute but is one or more function(s)).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, in Python, that is done using s property, exactly. And because of that, implementing a `get_age` method is an anti-pattern in Python.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher. Would you mind giving a concrete example to illustrate your explanation as I couldn't follow it. Then the comment from zvone made me more confused!

Comment: Yes, you can simply do that. It has absolutely no point. I'd guess whoever wrote that came from another language (e.g. Java) where preemptively writing getters and setters is the only way to be able to add behaviour later on, but Python does not have that limitation - when you actually have a need to intercept attribute access, you can do it with a property _without_ changing the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a function like `get_age`, a property should be used. Both approaches have the advantage over a direct attribute access that later changes to the way how the requested data is retrieved by the object don't require changes to the way the data is accessed from outside of the object.

Example:

Initial code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self._age = age

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

print(Student(23).age)
```

Can be changed (just an example, don't do date calculation like that) to:

```
from datetime import date

class Student:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self._birthyear = date.today().year - age

    @property
    def age(self):
        return date.today().year - self._birthyear

print(Student(23).age)
```

The last line accessing the age didn't change.

Comment: What did you mean by **both** approaches? Did you mean the **method** `get_age()` and the **@property** `age()` were better than `self.age = age`? Thanks.

Comment: @Nemo Right, the approach with an explicit getter and the preferable approach with a property.